# Read/write request Waiting queue and waiting time in Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, queue, threadpool, metrics

I'm new to Apache Cassandra and I'm working on research about it. Especially the waiting queue length and waiting time for read/write request.

Apache Cassandra is based on the SDEA (Stage-driven-event-archetecture). That means for each request, for example read request, it'll be put in a queue to be processed. Based on this, there's should be some metrics for the waiting queue and waiting time for each request.

According to the post in this link: https://www.pythian.com/blog/guide-to-cassandra-thread-pools/, the queue is based on the messaging service part.

Meanwhile, I did some search and found that my question is still a ticket for the Cassandra developers: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8398. The ticket has been there for a long time.

I also noticed that I can get this information with the usage of tpstats. However, to get this information I need to run the command in the terminal and print it out. So it's not accurate at all for my case.

I'm wondering anyone could have some hints, on where should I start to get the information/metrics of the **waiting time and queue length for each request**.

Thanks!

Steven

Comment: Try connecting to JMX port and see the MBeans

Comment: try [this doc](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html) and look PendingTasks in the threadpool metrics mbean

Comment: @Sreekar Thanks for the information. I have tried with the JMX and see the data in MBeans. However, just like I mentioned in my question, I need to refresh the value in Jconsole to get the updated value for my matrix. It's not exactly what I want. Specifically I kindly want to track the information for each request. For example, when each request comes in to the server, what's the queue length already existed and what's the waiting time to serve this request. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @LHWizad Thanks for update. For the threadpool metrics, especially the pendingTasks, it's Number of queued tasks queued up on this pool. I'm not sure whether this queued tasks including other internal task like gossip request. Also, my real problem is when each request comes in to the server, what's the queue length already existed and what's the waiting time to serve this request. Thanks again!

Comment: You said, "I also noticed that I can get this information with the usage of tpstats.". Where in tpstats can you see that? I think you are referring to the wait time in the queue, right?